# Subfigures always are vertical aligned

Tags: floats, subfloats, subfig

Following is my code. I have tried minipage and subfigure. I don't know why. 3 Pictures are always vertically aligning. I want to be horizontally aligned with 2 column width.

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot/messages_accounts.eps}
\caption{CDF of amount of messages collected for each account.
  The account that collected the most messages is info@mailinator.com.
  It has 34,022 messages.}
\label{fig:messages_accounts_cdf}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot/cluster.eps}
\caption{CDF of amount of messages in each cluster.
  There are 1,024,431 clusters in total.
  The biggest cluster has 2349 messages in it.
  99.1\% of clusters have less or equal 10 email messages in it.}
\label{fig:cluster_cdf}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{plot/class_results.png}
\caption{Email Categories Results}
\label{fig:results}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure*}
```

[image]

Comment: Does it work better if you remove the blank lines between the subfigures?

Comment: OMFG, I can't believe it's this easy!!!!!!!!!!!!! You just saved my life!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: subfigures are positioned exactly the same  as letters `ab` side by side `a b` side by side with a space or a line break if needed, `a<blank line>b` separate paragraphs so vertically stacked.